Is Trump the first politician to have their own meme stock?
CNN says that Truth Social (stock) is essentially a meme stock associated with Trump. Is Trump the first politician to capitalize on their fame to sell a meme stock? (N.B. The stock's ticker is DJT--Donald Trump's initials.)

Not sure that a stock is on topic even it it is own by a famous politician

"Meme stock" is not a matter of objective definition, and CNN is certainly not the arbiter of such a concept.

Trump is not the first presidential candidate to have shares (even significant ownership stakes) in a publicly traded company. Bloomberg was there before him.

Probably, but only because this is a new thing.
Just like there was a first President to ride in a motor vehicle. Or fly in an aircraft. Or be heard on the radio.
This is not a coolness of Trump, or a fail on previous Presidents.
